# Jersy REST service does not return object value from HashMap

Tags: java

We have created the Jersy REST service.
We are returning response object with 10 String fields and one Hash Map in format specified in below code snippet.

We could receive all the 10 string field values.

We can also see the HashMap with key/values when access it from client program.

CustomObject in HashMap became String when access it from client program.

so it throws exception

Listcom.tetherfi.restful.model.AppTypeData@2dc0f069
Test
err: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.tetherfi.restful.model.AppTypeData.

We use Moxy to do the mapping. Please advise whether there is a way to retain the object value.

Response object from Jersy service

@XmlRootElement
public class ServiceRespParams {

```
private String param1;
private String param2;
private String param3;
private String param4;
private String param5;

private HashMap<String,ArrayList<AppTypeData>>hm;

public HashMap<String, ArrayList<AppTypeData>> getHm() {
    return hm;
}

public void setHm(HashMap<String, ArrayList<AppTypeData>> hm) {
    this.hm = hm;
}
```

Client code

public class Client {

```
public ServiceResponse postRequest(ServiceRequest request) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("JerseyClient");
    ServiceResponse serviceResponse = null;
    WebTarget webTarget = null;
    Response response = null;

    // creating client with MOXy JSON

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    try {
    String url = "http://localhost:9080/Rest_ProxyLayer/webapi/doc01";
    logger.info("Sending Request.... "+url);
        webTarget = client.target(url).property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000)
                .property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 1000);
        logger.info("Request Sent...");
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        response = invocationBuilder.get();
        logger.info("Response Status :"+response.getStatus());
        serviceResponse = response.readEntity(ServiceResponse.class);

        System.out.println("Response from service"+ serviceResponse.getHm().get("CreditCard").get(0).getParam1());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error!! Check connection..", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serviceResponse;
}
```

}

It throws class cast exception when try to access the method.
System.out.println("Response from service"+ serviceResponse.getHm().get("CreditCard").get(0).getParam1());

Output from Rest service. Hashmap entries are below. It shows object but it seems to be converted to string.

HM: {CreditCard=[com.tetherfi.restful.model.AppTypeData@1b6c278e, com.tetherfi.restful.model.AppTypeData@208f5a00]}

Thanks
Vinoth

Comment: can you update your rest client ?

Comment: I have added the rest client

Comment: can you add it the result of the following exp to a hashmap serviceResponse.getHm().get("CreditCard").get(0).getParam1(). i:e your your user defined one